# Getting Multiline haskell function to work in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I created this haskell function to remove odd numbers from a list and was trying in ghci. I keep getting the error below though I have enabled the multiline mode and used 4 spaces for indentation.

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let removeOdds nums =
Prelude|     if null nums
Prelude|     then []
Prelude|     else
Prelude|         if (mod (head nums)/2) == 0
Prelude|         then (head nums) : (removeOdds(tail nums))
Prelude|         else removeOdds(tail nums)
Prelude|
```

:11:5:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

I read [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Common_Misunderstandings#Guards) page about the common mistable newbie's will make and I changed my code as below

```
Prelude> let removeOdds nums =
Prelude|     do if null nums
Prelude|         then []    
Prelude|         else 
Prelude|           do if mod((head nums)/2) == 0
Prelude|               then head nums: removeOdds(tail nums)   
Prelude|               else removeOdds(tail nums)
Prelude| 

<interactive>:47:5:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Now I ended with a new error. It appears the indentation is a tough thing to get around in haskell.

Comment: Btw - entering in multi-line statements in ghci is a pain. I usually use an editor window side-by-side to the console window running ghci. Invoke ghci with `ghci program.hs`. Use `:r` to reload `program.hs`  after you change it in the editor. Also have a look at the `:e`  and the `:set editor` commands. Also see the [__Loading source files__](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#loading-source-files) in the GHCi manual.

Comment: A common source of multiline functions is reinventing the wheel: `let removeOdds = filter even`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement needs to be indented at least one more space:

```
Prelude> let removeOdds nums =
Prelude|      if null nums

Complete example:

Prelude> let removeOdds nums =
Prelude|      if null nums
Prelude|      then []
Prelude|      else
Prelude|          if (mod (head nums) 2) == 0
Prelude|          then (head nums) : (removeOdds(tail nums))
Prelude|          else removeOdds(tail nums)
Prelude|
Prelude>
```

Comment: Prelude> mod (head [10,20,30])/2

<interactive>:153:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Fractional (a -> a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. (Fractional (a -> a), Integral a) => a -> a

Answer (score 3):

I use curly braces in GHCi when defining multiline functions. They allow you to just paste in a big block of Haskell code like you would usually write.

```
λ :{
| let
| -- type or paste here, e.g.,
| removeOdds :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
| removeOdds nums =
|   if null nums
|   then []
|   else -- ...
| :}
λ removeOdds [1,2,3,4]
[2,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also be good to note that when you aren't in the REPL and therefore don't require `let`, then you don't need so much indentation:

```
removeOdds nums =
  if null nums
  then []
  else
    if (mod (head nums) 2) == 0
    then (head nums) : (removeOdds(tail nums))
    else removeOdds(tail nums)
```